# User Capabilities in wordpress subsite

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone explain me

a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}

a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}

What are a, s and b here? and If I create a multisite what it will be for subsite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is serialized content.
You can generate it from an array for example with `serialize($array);` or decode the above with `unserialize(a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";})` to get the usable array.

As far as I know, `a` stands for array. `s` stands for string. The number behind it, is for the length.

So `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}` 1 Array, String with 13 characters, String with 1 character.

DOCs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php